# How do I change Tesseract submenu to the right without things changing?

Tags: fonts, colors, size, tesseract, submenu

I have Tesseract theme with Beaver Builder. 
I finally got the header to show my submenu the way I want it (with spaces between the options) though I would like to change the submenu font size and hover color.

My main problem is that I want the header menu to show over in the right block but it won't allow the menu options to be a different color (not really sure how it changed anyway) and it won't change the hover color...they are just all smooshed together when they are in the right block. Is there a way to change the font/color/hover in the right block. I've tried to change all the settings with css but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Which Tesseract theme you are using?

In Free theme( current version **3.8.6** ) from the version **3.8.5** onwards Tesseract introduce menu color changing option with hover too.

And in Tesseract Designer Theme the option is already there. 
Avail this feature by following path ( applicable for both theme)

**Appearance -> Customize -> Header option -> Header Color.** 
Use Header Link Color and Header Hovered Link Color.

Thanks.